# bash script for quick replacement of classNames in React project in Webstorm

Tags: reactjs, bash

I have a react project. I need to replace in my jsx and tsx files `className="some class"` with `className={cx("some class")}`, under condition that the existing className does not already contain `cx` function. I would like to do it with help of a bash script.

Here is what I have so far, but it does not work as it should (it changed only one random file):

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f \( -name "*.jsx" -o -name "*.tsx" \) | while read -r file; do
    sed -i.bak -E '/className="[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+"/ {
        /className={cx\(/! {
            s/className="([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"/className={cx("\1")}/g
        }
    }' "$file"
done

echo "Replacement completed."
```

Can anyone help so that it goes through all the folders and jsx/tsx files of the project?

Comment: Not sure why 2 vote-to-close and downvotes, as I see much worse questions everyday /-;! ... What you have seems like it should work, so wee need better evidence. Add `echo "file=$file"` inside the loop before the `sed` and see if that gives you any ideas. Update your Q with findings from that reserach. Good luck.

Comment: Does your `sed` command really work? Test on one file.

Comment: What's the point of the `while read` loop? Add `-exec sed -i.bak -E ... -- {} +` to the end of your `find` command.

Comment: Note that `-print` is only a default `find` action under limited circumstances -- it's much better to be explicit about it (and better than _that_ to use `-print0` instead when handling filenames; unlike a newline, a NUL can't exist within a file and be used for injection attacks).

Comment: That said, right now, this is arguably too broad to be on-topic: you've got two moving parts (the `find` part and the `sed` part), where the question would be better narrowed to only cover one or the other; that's in keeping with the "minimal" part of the [mre] definition, as well.

Comment: (to be clear what I meant about injection attacks -- think about what happens after someone runs `d=$'.hidden/\n/etc/passwd\n'; mkdir -p -- "$d" && touch "$d/hi.jsx"` -- you don't want your code trying to run `sed` on `/etc/passwd`)

Comment: Anyhow -- it's easy to test the pieces on their own; take off the `| while read -r` from your `find` and you'll see if you've hit one of the places where the automatic addition of `-print` isn't happening; take out the `find` and run `sed` directly if your concern is whether _that_ expression is correct. No need to keep them melded together, and once you narrow down what's wrong you can ask a clearer question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all advice on it. I modified the code by removing `while read` and by adding -exec at the end of find as suggested but Charles Duffy and Ed Morton. I also changed the directory from `.` to more specific one (`./src`) and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all you'd need is (untested):

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.jsx' -o -name '*.tsx' \) -exec \
sed -i.bak -E 's/(.*className=)"([^"]+)"/\1{cx("\2")}/' {} +
```

since the string you want to replace, `className="some class"`, has `"..."` around the part after the `=` while the similar string you do not want to match, `className={cx("some class")}` has `{...}` instead of `"..."` around the part after the `=`. So, there appears to be no reason to test for `cx(...)` already being present since `className={..}` wouldn't match a regexp like `className="[^"]+"` that'd match your target string anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestions. I used your shorter syntax with `-exec` at the end. But as to regular expressions I needed to keep the ones I had, because with the one you proposed the replaced classname did not have "" in the result (it looked like this className={cx(some class)}

Comment: @bakrall I added the quotes around "some class" in the replacement now.